# thread-safety in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading

If my code has a terrible race condition on a variable and I get inconsistent results with it with my `Rack::Lock middleware` disabled by `config.threadsafe!` option, how can I ensure to avoid thread-safety issues within my app on a threaded server? What measures I have to take?

Is there a difference between how it will get executed on threaded/multiple process servers?

**UPDATE**

This is the code snippet from an article with a race condition :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 @counter = 0

class << self
 attr_accessor :counter
end

trap(:INFO) {
$stderr.puts "Count: #{UsersController.counter}"
}

def index
  counter = self.class.counter # read
  sleep(0.1)
  counter += 1                 # update
  sleep(0.1)
  self.class.counter = counter # write

  @users = User.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @users }
  end
end
```

Comment: If you want an answer that is not just purely theoretical you should include the problematic code.

Comment: I added the snippet..

Comment: What does the counter actually do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two components of a race condition are shared resource and concurrent access to it, to get rid of the race condition - eliminate one of them (or both)

So avoid global variables (class variables are in fact global too), if you absolutely cannot - then eliminate parallel access by using mutex.

```
self.class.semaphore = Mutex.new
```

and

```
self.class.semaphore.synchronize{ 
    #here goes your unsafe code
    self.class.counter += 1
}
```

But with lots of complicated synchronization you may run into problems with deadlocks, if some code requires two mutexes being locked at once, so it's better not to have shared resources in first place.